# Changing background color with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hi I'm trying to make a row of divs blink, **but one div should blink at a time**.(not all the divs should blink at the same time [i could do that])..

kind of like the way a traffic light works. each light is part of a row of lights and each light turns on and off one at a time going through a loop. in my case the blinking is meant to remind the users that the divs or clickable.

I put each box in an array but I couldn't figure out how to change the color of each box in a loop. I guess a way to solve this is by adding and removing a classes that contains the colors and it should do that after 1 or 2 seconds so setInterval should come in to play. I couldn't figure it out.

but here is my sad code

```
            var arr =[];
        $(".boxes").each(function(){
            arr.push($(this));
        });     

      function bgChange(){

            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            arr[i].addClass("red"); 
            }           
        }
            setInterval(bgChange, 2000);

    });
```

I'm looking to forward to seeing the creative ways that you guys could come up with to make this work.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/6sTMD/)
Thank You in advanced

Comment: Yes, I will study this. thanks for the response.

Comment: Was that in response to my earlier comment? Sorry, I had removed that because I posted the link as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing it with the below code. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/6sTMD/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = [];
    var i = 0;

    $(".boxes").each(function () {
        arr.push($(this));
    });

    function bgChange() {
        for (var count = 0; count < arr.length; count++) {
            if (i == count) arr[count].css('background-color', 'red');
            else arr[count].css('background-color', 'white');
        }
        i++;
        if (i === arr.length) i = 0;
    }
    setInterval(bgChange, 2000);

});
```

**EDIT:** If you want to do it by using CSS classes, modify the for loop to be like below:

```
    for (var count = 0; count < arr.length; count++) {
        if (i == count) arr[count].addClass('red');
        else arr[count].removeClass('red');
    }
```

Comment: I understand but now i want to kick it up a notch lets say I want to change the divs into diff colors not just red. like the 3rd div will be blue.

Comment: What would be the logic? Like how should the code determine which should be blue and which should be red?

Comment: I really don't know i could ask this in a new question since it's kind of a diff question. but im assuming that that there are if statements and the colors change depending on where the div is in the array. if you could figure that out that would be great. but for now ill accept your answer

Comment: @user2537537: Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/6sTMD/4/). In this the `blue div` is determined randomly. The `red div` logic remains same as old. I have added a case using `do{}while` loop to avoid `i` and `j` having same value. Check in console for the values of `i` and `j` during every change.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
    var arr = $(".boxes");

    var current = 0;
    function bgChange(){
         if (arr.length > 0){
            //Remove class of all items
            arr.removeClass("red");
            //Set Class of current item
            arr.eq(current).addClass("red");     
            //Increase the current index
            current = (current + 1) % arr.length;
         }
    }
    setInterval(bgChange, 2000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6sTMD/3/)

Comment: @user2537537: this uses `addClass` and `removeClass` to avoid putting css styles into javascript (separation of concerns)

Comment: arr[((current+arr.length)-1)%arr.length].removeClass("red"); im not sure how this remove the red class that was previously added

Comment: @user2537537: `((current+arr.length)-1)%arr.length` returns the previous index

Comment: @user2537537: I added an easier to understand demo

Comment: +1, I like the second demo more. I wrote something on similar lines, but my sample is more like vanilla JS.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply I understand the first and the second demo.

Comment: @user2537537: I myself recommend the second demo as it's easier to understand and counts for case when there are no items in the array (a check to ensure no exception to be thrown).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $boxes = $(".boxes");

function bgChange(){
    var $active = $boxes.filter('.red'), $next = $active.next('.boxes');
    if(!$next.length){
        $next = $boxes.first();
    }

    $active.removeClass('red');
    $next.addClass('red');
}
setInterval(bgChange, 2000);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7MMxh/)

Comment: +1, nice and easily understandable. Just one question, how does it work the first time when none of the boxes have 'red' class?

Comment: @Harry then `!$next.length` condition will fire setting `next` to the first item

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `toggleClass` to set the class for the current box:

```
var boxes = $(".boxes");
var current = 0;

function animate() {
    boxes.each(function(index) {
        $(this).toggleClass("red", index == current);
    });
    current = (current + 1) % boxes.length;
    setTimeout(animate, 1000);
};

animate();
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmwmx/2/)